# C# MVC application using TempData - session vs cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies

I have an MVC application and I am using TempData as a vehicle to store data on the server as the user navigates to different sections of the site.

When the user logs into the site, I save pieces of information in a model, I JsonConvert.SerializeObject the model, and then save the information in TempData.  This is the line of code that I use:

```
 TempData["participantSessionData"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(participantData);
```

Then, I execute a redirect using this code:

```
 return RedirectToAction("Index", "MainPage");
```

In the MainPage controller, in the Index action, I have this code:

```
  TempData.Keep("participantSessionData");
  ParticipantSessionData participantSessionData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ParticipantSessionData>((string)TempData["participantSessionData"]);
```

This works exactly as I anticipated and the data in TempData becomes available to the MainPage controller.

I believe that as the amount of data stored in TempData increases, the cookies that .net is maintaining grows to the point where I start to get errors telling me http header sizes are to large.

I'm thinking that if I store TempData in the session instead of cookies, I may be able to alleviate this problem.

So, I added the following to my Startup.cs:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<System.Data.IDbConnection>((s) =>
        {

            IDbConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("accurecord"));

            conn.Open();
            return conn;
        });
        services.AddTransient<IMainPageRepository, MainPageRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<IHomeRepository, HomeRepository>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddSessionStateTempDataProvider();
        services.AddSession();

    }
```

And I added this to the Configure:

```
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSession();
```

Now, when I run the application, and I redirect to the MainPage controller and I have a breakpoint set on the line where I deserialize, and I put a watch on the TempData, there is no data.

Is there something else that I need to set up in the application to store TempData in session as opposed to cookies?

Thank you.

Comment: `CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2` <-- This is unnecessary in modern versions, and might be the cause of the issue.

Comment: @Dai  Thanks for the feedback.  I just reviewed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235#configure-the-tempdata-provider and it states "The order of middleware is important. Call UseSession after UseRouting and before UseEndpoints."  I changed my code to place UseSession after UseRouting and the TempData is getting passed correctly.  Now I just need to see if this change resolves my http header size issue.  Thanks again.